# ASPOSE :How to Remove a Cell in ASPOSE

Tags: aspose, aspose-cells, aspose.words

How to remove a specific cell from a row in aspose?

The equivalent method of RemoveCell() in NPOI

Answer (score 2):

You may try to use Worksheet.Cells.DeleteRange() method to remove cell(s) accordingly, see the sample code below:
e.g
Sample code:

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook("e:\\test2\\Book1.xlsx");
Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
//Delete the range A1:N36 and shifts the cells upwards.
worksheet.Cells.DeleteRange(0, 0, 35, 13, ShiftType.Up);
workbook.Save("e:\\test2\\out1.xlsx");
```

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose

Comment: Thank you Very much ..... is  there any method very takes Cell as parameter to delete the cell

Comment: No, there is no such overload for DeleteRange() method but you may easily do that using existing Cells.DeleteRange() method, e.g //Delete the cell/range B2 and shifts the cells upwards.
worksheet.Cells.DeleteRange(1, 1, 1, 1, ShiftType.Up);

Comment: ok ..anyway i have ached my requirement using below code.
workSheet.Cells.ClearFormats(intRow, intCol, intRow, intCol);
workSheet.Cells.ClearContents(intRow, intCol, intRow, intCol);